# Create populated workbook works for first iteration, but not on further ones

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having some issues with some VBA I've written, the purpose of the VBA is to take data from a master spreadsheet, and create a set of additional workbooks for each line manager.

It will take the entirety of one sheet from the master workbook, titled "RoleAccess" and copy the entire sheet to each new workbook into Sheet1 (then later on re-name Sheet1 to RoleAccess), then it will go through a list of managers in the master workbook from the EmailList sheet and determine the access that each user under the manager has, and paste that into Sheet2 of the new workbook (then later on re-name Sheet2 to UserAccess).

This works fantastic for the first manager on the list, but the subsequent managers seem to get their RoleAccess sheet perfect, and the header for UserAccess, but they don't get the rest of the rows populated. I've verified that there's no issues with linking by inserting messageboxes, and it doesn't error at all, it's just failing to paste the data after the first workbook is complete.

Code below:

```
Sub Create_Output_Files()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim RA As Worksheet
    Dim UA As Worksheet
    Dim Sum_WS As Worksheet
    Dim EL As Worksheet
    Dim LM As Worksheet

    Set RA = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RoleAccess")
    Set UA = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UserAccess")
    Set Sum_WS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
    Set EL = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("EmailList")
    Set LM = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("LineManagers")



    'Determine size of copy
    i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(RA.Range("A:A"))
    j = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(RA.Range("A1:XFD1"))
    k = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(UA.Range("A1:XFD1"))
    l = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(EL.Range("A:A"))
    m = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(UA.Range("A:A"))


    For n = 2 To l
        'Activate and copy data from Role Access sheet
        RA.Activate
        RA.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(i, j)).Copy
        'Create new workbook
        Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
        Set ws1 = NewWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = NewWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        'Paste Role Access data into the workbook
        ws1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(i, j)).PasteSpecial xlValues
        ws1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(i, j)).PasteSpecial xlFormats
        ws1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(i, j)).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        'Freeze view
        ws1.Range("C2").Select
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
        'Activate and copy header data from User Access sheet
        UA.Activate
        UA.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, k)).Copy
        'Paste User Access header into new workbook
        ws2.Activate
        ws2.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, k)).PasteSpecial xlValues
        ws2.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, k)).PasteSpecial xlFormats
        ws2.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, k)).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        'Activate and copy iterative data for each manager
        For p = 2 To m
            If UA.Cells(p, 1) = EL.Cells(n, 1) Then
                UA.Rows(p).Copy Destination:=ws2.Rows(p)
            Else
                'Nothing
            End If
        Next p
        'Change sheet name
        ws1.Name = "RoleAccess"
        ws2.Name = "UserAccess"
            'Delete extra sheets
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        NewWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Select
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
        'Save and close workbook
        NewWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\RemTP\Output Files\" & EL.Cells(n, 1)
        NewWorkbook.Close
    Next n

    'Re-activate summary screen
    Sum_WS.Activate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Any ideas at all would be highly appreciated, as it's driving me slightly up the wall!

Cheers

Comment: Try to debug your code step by step and see where it doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with debugging, best I've done is added a msgbox under the UA.Rows(p).Copy Destination:=ws2.Rows(p) that is:

Msgbox UA.Cells(p,1) & " - " & EL.Cells(n,1)

Just to make sure that it's finding the correct data, and it is. However, I'm unsure how to test why the paste itself isn't working. It's like it finds the correct answer to the if statement, fails to execute the paste, but never errors.

Comment: Try stepping through your code as FunThomas says using F8. Also try inserting a breakpoint at `If UA.Cells(p, 1) = EL.Cells(n, 1)` to check the condition is met. Possibly a silly question, but are you sure it isn't pasting, because you could have big gaps (possibly) in your output. If the condition is met when p=20 and when p=500 there will be 480 blank rows in between.

Comment: A debugger is a real important tool when it comes to coding (or finding bugs in your code). Get an introduction for example at https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/vba_debug2010.php It's really worth the time to learn the basics of it.

Comment: Don't use copy and paste - just set one range equal to the other...

Comment: I'm an idiot. It was pasting, but starting at row 4xx instead of row 2 because of the values I set.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found: User error. Information was posting at a lower row, as the data was ordered alphabetically. Therefore, workbook 2 had values starting at row 4xx instead of row 2.

Solution is to write a loop that starts pasting at row 2 always.

Edit: 
Possibly not the most efficient code in the world, but the following was used:

```
    'Activate and copy iterative data for each manager
    For p = 2 To m
        If UA.Cells(p, 1) = EL.Cells(n, 1) Then
            UA.Rows(p).Copy Destination:=ws2.Rows(p)
        Else
            'Nothing
        End If
    Next p
    'Remove blank lines
    While ws2.Cells(2, "A") = ""
        Rows(2).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Wend
```